# Ajustar AlertDialog com Teclado Aberto

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Estou com o seguinte problema tenho um AlertDialog

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando o teclado é aberto, o dialog sobe, mas parte do dialog fica escondido.. ele não ajusta o *height* conforme o teclado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

XML do dialog:

```
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout 
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/root_view"
                  android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                  android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                  android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:id="@+id/txtCliente"
                android:text="Cliente : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:id="@+id/txtData"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text="Data : XX/YY/ZZZZ hh:MM:ss" />



        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:text="Motivo" />

            <Spinner
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/spinner"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:lines="3"
                android:maxLength="200"
                android:id="@+id/txtObs"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Código que gera o AlertDialog

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
View dialog_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_motivonaoatendimento, null);

AlertDialog.Builder db = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

db.setView(dialog_layout);
db.setTitle("Não Atendimento");
db.setPositiveButton("Confirmar", new
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });

db.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", null);

final AlertDialog alertDialog = db.create();
alertDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

db.show();
```

Uma observação que notei, parece que a `scrollview` não funciona. Em alguns testes vi que o "primeiro" layout ele não obedece, e a `scrollview` te obriga a colocar o layout como "pai".

Não sei se essa pode ser a causa do problema..

Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Não tem como colocar um outro layout um nível acima do scrollview?
layout>scroll>layout>widgets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se o `EditText` estiver dentro do seu `Dialog`, acontecerá isso mesmo. Uma solução possível é você definir o [`InputType`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html) do seu `EditText`. Sendo assim você conseguirá utilizar o evento do seu teclado, no qual ao clicar no <kbd>DONE</kbd>, ele (o teclado) desaparecerá mostrando o diálogo completo com os devidos botões. Veja:

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:lines="3"
android:maxLength="200"
android:id="@+id/txtObs"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:inputType="text"/>
```

Imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja alguns exemplos aqui nesse [artigo sobre inputType](http://alvinalexander.com/android/android-edittext-inputtype-formatting-examples-xml-options-keyboard)<sup>(en)</sup>.

Detalhes

- [Specifying the Input Method Type](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html)<sup>(en)</sup>